# My biggest mistake as a Programmer - For Loops

Tags: java

I think this is my biggest mistake and I'm starting to realize that I have repeated tons of times in my web app.

Everytime I want to compare if a property from a List is the same as another property of a List i make a double for loop.

Of course this is not bad for my website for now but once it has Millions of users it will start to slowdown.

This is my typical mistake:

In this case I have a `List<String>` with the usernames of the logged users and I want to return to the frontend the full User information for each user.

This seems very bad because I need to loop over all the Users even tho I only need to get the information for the online users.

***Can anyone help me with this? Is this bad practices? What can I do?***

```
 @Autowired
private ActiveUsers activeUsers;

 @RequestMapping(value = "/loggedUsers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<User> getLoggedUsers() {
    List<User> users = User.getUsers();
    List<User> onlineUsers = new ArrayList<>();
    for(User user : users) {
        for(String username : activeUsers.getUsers()) {
            if(username.equals(user.getUsername())) {
                onlineUsers.add(user);
            }
        }
    }
    return onlineUsers;
}
```

Comment: Would it be possible to use a HashSet instead of a simple List? That way, you can just have one for loop over the first list, then a HashSet.contains(element) on a second, which should be an O(1) operation. This wouldn't work if there could be duplicate elements, though.

Comment: Please change the title to summarize the actual question. Also see [ask].

Comment: @redsoxfantom That's still `O(n)` at the end.

Comment: If I may notice something else: If I work on a team with you and I read `activeUsers.getUsers()`, I expect it to return some `Collection`/`Stream` of type `User`. Better to call it `getUserNames()`!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a `Map<String,User>`. Have `User.getUsers()` return that `Map` (it should probably be cached, so that you don't have to generate that `Map` each time you call that method). The key would be the user name and the value would be the corresponding `User`.

Now, the nested loops can be replaced by a single loop:

```
List<User> getLoggedUsers() {
    Map<String,User> users = User.getUsers();
    List<User> onlineUsers = new ArrayList<>();
    for (String username : activeUsers.getUsers()) {
        User user = users.get(username);
        if(user != null) {
            onlineUsers.add(user);
        }
    }
    return onlineUsers;
}
```

with Java 8, this can be simplified to:

```
List<User> getLoggedUsers() {
    Map<String,User> users = User.getUsers();
    return activeUsers.getUsers()
                      .stream()
                      .map(users::get)
                      .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: But `User.getUsers()` is a function that get's the users from the database and returns a List<User> like this `String hql = "FROM User";
            Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
            users = query.list();`

Comment: @user9658240 You can replace it with a new method that calls the original method and creates the Map from the List (I'd still suggest caching that Map).

Comment: @user9658240 creating the Map from the List is as simple as `Map<String,User> users = userList.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(User::getUsername,Function.identity()));`

Answer (score 0):

Convert `List<User> users` to `Map<String,User> users` (where the key is username). Then you can skip 1 for loop and make get at O(1) time.

```
Map<> myset = User.getUsers();
```

Now you can check in a single for loop and check if the `activeUsers` contains `users`.

Comment: I actually had map in my mind. But somehow wrote set in a hurry. Corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

How I'd do it:

```
@Autowired
private ActiveUsers activeUsers;

@RequestMapping(value = "/loggedUsers", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<User> getLoggedUsers() {
    final List<User> users = User.getUsers();
    final List<User> activeUsersList = activeUsers.getUsers();

    return users.stream()
                .filter(user -> activeUsersList.contains(user))
                .colect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Using streams you could find starting from Java 8 is really nice and not hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Use this line of code:

```
Set<User> onlineUsers = users.stream().filter(
    user -> activeUsers.getUsers().contains(user.getUserNmae())).collect(Collectors.toSet());
```